# Bowling: Thumb exit point

Tags: bowling

I've watched a lot of YouTube videos about bowling a hook ball, but there's one aspect I'm still unclear on.

When bowling a hook ball, should my thumb exit prior to or during outward rotation?

In other words, should I commence outward rotation with my thumb still in the ball, or should my fingertips/palm be the sole points of contact during this phase?